# Is there a way to disable the recent Amazon Redshift update (from Dec-8-2023, see below) that uses "machine learning" to create new distribution keys?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift Update: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-redshift-advisor-sort-distribution-key-recommendations/

Essentially, this update is killing my existing ETL processes that use ALTER TABLE APPEND because it will create new distribution and sort keys on existing tables, causing the above command to fail.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a way to disable this update or is there another workaround besides making explicit calls to create distribution and sort keys on every table?

I have created new keys for tables, but am trying to avoid doing this for all processes I currently have running.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give example DDL of a table being appended to / automatically updated, ***and*** the DDL for the source table being append from, ***and*** the DDL for the APPEND causing the changes? *(Essentially, a [mre] that can reliably replicate the scenario described. Perhaps, for example, the two tables have different keys.)* Unless dist/sort are AUTO, this shouldn't happen (to my knowledge).

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you for your quick reply. I will delete this question and follow the rules next time; I realized I have diststyle set to auto on my staging table create commands, and this new feature started creating distkeys because of that.

Comment: Leave the question, your comment may help others :)

Comment: Yeah I had that alter table append issue, especially when I would create a new table from an original and it ended up with the wrong sort key. Not sure how to help you, but ur not alone my friend. Maybe set the key manually and then it won’t override it?